# How to prevent Device Driver Installation Wizard warning at end of inno setup install?

Tags: inno-setup

I am using inno setup to install a vb6 application and drivers. Everything works fine on x86 and x64, but at the end of the installation on Windows 7 a Device Driver Installation Wizard message box is displayed saying: 'You have to run the 64-bit version of DPInst.exe on this machine. Contact the vendor that provided you this software'.

I am using the version of DPInst.exe that comes from the Windows 7 driver development kit and have tried compiling the installer on the Windows 7 machine, but received the same results.

Can anyone please point out what I am missing?

The script is reasonably large, so here is what I think is the relevant code:

```
[Setup]
ArchitecturesInstallIn64BitMode=x64

[Run]
Filename: {app}\DigidownHost.exe;   Description: {cm:LaunchProgram,DigidownHost}; Flags: nowait postinstall skipifsilent
Filename: {app}\Drivers\DPInst.exe; Description: {cm:LaunchProgram,DigidownHost}; Flags: skipifsilent waituntilterminated

[Files]
Source: TOBE Installed\DigidownHost.exe;  DestDir: {app}; Flags: ignoreversion

Source: TOBE Installed\XZip.dll;          DestDir: {sys};               Flags: regserver;   Check: not Is64BitInstallMode
Source: TOBE Installed\MSCOMM32.OCX;      DestDir: {sys};               Flags: regserver;   Check: not Is64BitInstallMode
Source: TOBE Installed\FTChipID.dll;      DestDir: {sys};                                   Check: not Is64BitInstallMode
Source: TOBE Installed\ftd2xx.dll;        DestDir: {sys};                                   Check: not Is64BitInstallMode

Source: TOBE Installed\XZip.dll;          DestDir: {syswow64};          Flags: regserver;   Check: Is64BitInstallMode
Source: TOBE Installed\MSCOMM32.OCX;      DestDir: {syswow64};          Flags: regserver;   Check: Is64BitInstallMode
Source: TOBE Installed\FTChipID.dll;      DestDir: {syswow64};                              Check: Is64BitInstallMode
Source: TOBE Installed\ftd2xx.dll;        DestDir: {syswow64};                              Check: Is64BitInstallMode

Source: TOBE Installed\Settings.ini;      DestDir: {app};               Flags: ignoreversion
Source: TOBE Installed\Drivers\*.*;       DestDir: {app}\drivers;       Flags: ignoreversion deleteafterinstall
Source: TOBE Installed\Drivers\amd64\*.*; DestDir: {app}\drivers\amd64; Flags: ignoreversion deleteafterinstall;  Check: Is64BitInstallMode
Source: TOBE Installed\Drivers\i386\*.*;  DestDir: {app}\drivers\i386;  Flags: ignoreversion deleteafterinstall;  Check: not Is64BitInstallMode
```

Comment: I assume you install the driver by running DPInst.exe from inno setup, do you get the same message if you run the exe from the command line on that machine?

Comment: I have tried running DPInst.exe from the command prompt and received the same message.

Comment: If this is the case, this problem is not related to Inno setup but to DPInst.exe.  From inno point of view you just need to provide a valid DPInst.exe (one which not emit any warning on the target system).
Dont forget to include the @jachguate in your comments if you want me to notice it trough the system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updated answer: 
It looks like, based on your script, you are running the same DPInst.exe both both 32 bit and 64 bit.  According to http://www.winvistatips.com/correct-version-dpinst-exe-use-windows-vista-32-64-bit-t438327.html, there are different versions of DPInst.exe for each platform.  So your script should be something like:

```
[Run]
Filename: {app}\Drivers\x86\DPInst.exe; Description: {cm:LaunchProgram,DigidownHost}; Flags: skipifsilent waituntilterminated; Check: Not Is64BitInstallMode
Filename: {app}\Drivers\amd64\DPInst.exe; Description: {cm:LaunchProgram,DigidownHost}; Flags: skipifsilent waituntilterminated; Check: Is64BitInstallMode
```

Original comment:
Can you post your InnoSetup script?
Could it be running the command twice accidentally?
Are you sure it's running the right DPInst.exe in your script?

Comment: This looks like a comment to the question, not like a valid answer to it.

Comment: Thanks for the help - couldn't see the wood for the trees - The problem was the two seemingly identical versions of DPInst (one seems to work only on x86, but the other seems to work only on x64 - I thought it was backward compatible - my bad).

Comment: Glad you got it working. Microsoft seems to like same file names for different versions of tools.